# GET http://localhost:3002/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OuMnixp net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I made a code that reflects the api value in real time using socketio as shown below, but an error like the title occurred, so please let me know what the problem is

on the error It says like this, but I don't know why
GET http://localhost:3002/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OuMq4L7 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

```
// Import necessary modules
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const request = require("request");

// Create Express app
const app = express();

// Set EJS as the view engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");

// Render the EJS file on a specific route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("busApi");
});

// Create HTTP server
const server = http.createServer(app);

// Set up Socket.IO connection
const io = socketIo(server);

const apiUrl =
  "http://apis.data.go.kr/1613000/BusLcInfoInqireService/getRouteAcctoBusLcList";

// Function to fetch data from the API
const fetchData = () => {
  const queryParams = {
    serviceKey:
      "serviceKey",
    pageNo: "1",
    numOfRows: "10",
    _type: "json",
    cityCode: "25",
    routeId: "DJB30300052",
  };

  request(
    {
      url: apiUrl,
      method: "GET",
      qs: queryParams,
    },
    (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
        return;
      }

      const jsonResponse = JSON.parse(body);
      const routeType = jsonResponse.response.body.items.item[0].routetp;
      console.log("Route Type:", routeType);

      // Emit the updated data to connected clients
      io.emit("routeTypeUpdated", routeType);
    }
  );
};

// Set up Socket.IO connection
io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("A user connected");

  // Emit initial data on connection
  fetchData();

  // Schedule periodic data updates (every 60 seconds)
  setInterval(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, 60000);

  // Handle disconnections
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("User disconnected");
  });
});

// Serve your API and Socket.IO on the same server
const PORT = 3002;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Real-Time Route Type</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Display the updated route type -->
<h1>Current Route Type: <span id="routeType"></span></h1>

<!-- Include Socket.IO client library -->
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.0.0/socket.io.min.js"></script>

<script>
    // Connect to the Socket.IO server
    const socket = io('http://localhost:3002');

    // Listen for the 'routeTypeUpdated' event
    socket.on('routeTypeUpdated', (routeType) => {
        // Update the displayed route type in the HTML
        document.getElementById('routeType').innerText = routeType;
    });

    // Additional client-side logic can be added here

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your server actually running? Have you started it and received the message _`Server is running on http://localhost:3002`_?

Comment: yes when i use npm run dev  I got this message

**(node:3704) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Server is running on http://localhost:3002